# HTTP response code: 411 for URL: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Tags: java, api, rest, twitter

Modified:

Reference :http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

I have get signature_base_string,signature_key,oauth_signature and all other parameters that are the same with twitter tutorial.

1. signature_base_string
   POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3005%252Fthe_dance%252Fprocess_callback%253Fservice_provider_id%253D11%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g%26oauth_nonce%3DQP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1272323042%26oauth_version%3D1.0
2. signature_key
   oauth_consumer_secret="MCD8BKwGdgPHvAuvgvz4EQpqDAtx89grbuNMRd7Eh98&"
3. oauth_signature
   8wUi7m5HFQy76nowoCThusfgB+Q=

Now I request http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token use "POST" method  and get response code 411. 
I use a servlet doGet() when I request it from my Firefox.
What do I miss in the code or any mistake?  Who can help me?

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String base_url="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    String oauth_callback="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json";
    String oauth_consumer_key="GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g";
    String oauth_consumer_secret="MCD8BKwGdgPHvAuvgvz4EQpqDAtx89grbuNMRd7Eh98&";
    String oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";


    int oauth_timestamp=1272323042;
    String oauth_version="1.0";
    String oauth_nonce="QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk";

    String oauth_signature="";

    String signature_base_string = null;
    try {
        signature_base_string = "POST"
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode(
                        "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                        "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder
                        .encode("oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11&oauth_consumer_key=GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g&oauth_nonce=QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1272323042&oauth_version=1.0",
                                "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(signature_base_string);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(
                oauth_consumer_secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(signature_base_string.getBytes());

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        oauth_signature=encoder.encode(digest);
        System.out.println(oauth_signature);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    URL url=new URL(base_url);

    HttpURLConnection httpURLCon=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(MyProxy.getProxy());


    httpURLCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth "+"oauth_nonce='QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk', oauth_callback='http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11', oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1', oauth_timestamp='1272323042', oauth_consumer_key='GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g', oauth_signature='8wUi7m5HFQy76nowoCThusfgB%2BQ%3D', oauth_version='1.0'");
    httpURLCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");


    /*Map<String,List<String>> headers= httpURLCon.getHeaderFields();

    Iterator<String> i=headers.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        String key=i.next();
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(headers.get(key).toString());
        System.out.println("====================");
    }
    */

    httpURLCon.connect();
    InputStream is=null;
    if (httpURLCon.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        is = httpURLCon.getErrorStream();
    } else {
        is = httpURLCon.getInputStream();
    }

    byte[] b=new byte[1024*4];
    int read;
    while((read=is.read(b))!=-1){
        response.getOutputStream().write(b,0,read);
    }
}
```

Message:
**ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved**

While trying to process the request:

POST /oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce='QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk', oauth_callback='http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11', oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1', oauth_timestamp='1272323042', oauth_consumer_key='GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g', oauth_signature='8wUi7m5HFQy76nowoCThusfgB%2BQ%3D', oauth_version='1.0'
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
X-D-Forwarder: yes
Max-Forwards: 10

The following error was encountered:

```
Invalid Request
```

Some aspect of the HTTP Request is invalid. Possible problems:

```
Missing or unknown request method
Missing URL
Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0)
Request is too large
Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests
Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed
```

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
Generated Fri, 08 Jul 2011 06:41:34 GMT by google.com (squid/2.7.STABLE6)

==========================================================

Reference :http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

I have get signature_base_string,signature_key,oauth_signature and all other parameters that are the same with twitter tutorial.

1. signature_base_string
   POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3005%252Fthe_dance%252Fprocess_callback%253Fservice_provider_id%253D11%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g%26oauth_nonce%3DQP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1272323042%26oauth_version%3D1.0
2. signature_key
   oauth_consumer_secret="MCD8BKwGdgPHvAuvgvz4EQpqDAtx89grbuNMRd7Eh98&"
3. oauth_signature
   8wUi7m5HFQy76nowoCThusfgB+Q=

Now I request http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token use "POST" method  and get response code 411. 
I use a servlet doGet() when I request it from my Firefox.
What do I miss in the code or any mistake?  Who can help me?

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String base_url="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    String oauth_callback="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json";
    String oauth_consumer_key="GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g";
    String oauth_consumer_secret="MCD8BKwGdgPHvAuvgvz4EQpqDAtx89grbuNMRd7Eh98&";
    String oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";


    int oauth_timestamp=1272323042;
    String oauth_version="1.0";
    String oauth_nonce="QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk";

    String oauth_signature="";

    String signature_base_string = null;
    try {
        signature_base_string = "POST"
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode(
                        "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                        "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder
                        .encode("oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11&oauth_consumer_key=GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g&oauth_nonce=QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1272323042&oauth_version=1.0",
                                "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(signature_base_string);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(
                oauth_consumer_secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(signature_base_string.getBytes());

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        oauth_signature=encoder.encode(digest);
        System.out.println(oauth_signature);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    URL url=new URL(base_url);

    HttpURLConnection httpURLCon=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(MyProxy.getProxy());


    httpURLCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth "+"oauth_nonce='QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk', oauth_callback='http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11', oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1', oauth_timestamp='1272323042', oauth_consumer_key='GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g', oauth_signature='8wUi7m5HFQy76nowoCThusfgB%2BQ%3D', oauth_version='1.0'");
    httpURLCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");


    /*Map<String,List<String>> headers= httpURLCon.getHeaderFields();

    Iterator<String> i=headers.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        String key=i.next();
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(headers.get(key).toString());
        System.out.println("====================");
    }
    */

    httpURLCon.connect();
    InputStream is=httpURLCon.getInputStream();
    byte[] b=new byte[1024*4];
    int read;
    while((read=is.read(b))!=-1){
        response.getOutputStream().write(b,0,read);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1313)
at com.twitterbridge.oauth.Oauth.doGet(Oauth.java:114)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise, if I may ask?

Comment: Check your oauth_callback, its value seems already be encoded. Try oauth_callback=http://... instead

Comment: **Never**, **Never**, and **Never** display your consumer secret on any post.

Comment: If you cut-pasted OAuth examples from Twitter, it won't help as the `oauth_timestamp` is extremely old and will never validate.

Answer (score 0):

Before I can help you, what your `InputStream` from your HTTP Error 411 state?

Add the following code.

```
InputStream is = null;
if (httpURLCon.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    is = httpURLCon.getErrorStream();
} else {
    is = httpURLCon.getInputStream();
}
```

---

**Update**: Your `Authorization` header value must **never** contain a space. The value must be `OAuth<space><comma-delimited-value-without-space>`.

Comment: I want to overwrite Twitter Api. because can not reach twitter directly.

Comment: you want to overwrite Twitter API? Why? If it works, it works! BTW, Twitter knows why they created the API as is.

Comment: I mean I want to write an api to connect twitter api and have the same function with it. some twitter client like twidroyd can use.

Comment: i add httpURLCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

Comment: i add httpURLCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");  and i've got the error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token". I think it works.but signature is error.

Comment: No, the signature is failing, so it's not working. Rather use an existsing API such as Scribe or joauth.

Comment: yes.the signature is error. i dont know how to get an correct one . I will try Scribe or joauth.